# converting a d3.csv method to d3.csv.parse method

Tags: javascript, parsing, d3.js, csv

I just need to draw a d3 barchart of data retrieved from an sql query, so I don't have a tsv or csv file but a string of data in csv format. I know I can use d3.csv.parse method but somehow I couldn't figure out how to convert the example code for the csv bar chart using the data from a file to csv.parse method for data contained in a string variable.

here is the example code for csv file:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", type, function(error, data) {
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) {  return d.letter; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);
```

here is the sample data for testing purposes and the code that doesn't work

```
var bardata="letter,frequency\nA,0.89\nB,0.71\nC,0.45";
d3.csv.parse(bardata,type, function(data) { 
    x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; })); 
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);
```

Apparently, I cannot simply replace a file with a var containing the contents of the file. What would be the best way to do it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 23):

`d3.csv.parse` accepts only two parameters — a string which contains your CSV data, and an accessor function which you can use to construct the data array. Note the difference between `d3.csv` and `d3.tsv`, which both also accept the callback function as a parameter.

```
letters = d3.csv.parse(bardata, function(d) {
    return {
        letter:d.letter, 
        frequency:+d.frequency
    };
});
```

This would parse CSV data in `bardata` and put the values  as an array in `letters`. In fact, the accessor function is optional. The following would also do the same thing:

```
letters = d3.csv.parse(bardata);
```

Once you have the array, you can build the bar chart as usual. See snippet below.

```js
var bardata="letter,frequency\nA,0.89\nB,0.71\nC,0.45";

var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1, .2);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

letters = d3.csv.parse(bardata, function(d) { 
    return {
        letter:d.letter, 
        frequency:+d.frequency
    }; 
});

x.domain(letters.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(letters, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"));

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left"));

svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(letters)
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.0.4/d3.min.js"></script>
```