# Copy data from csv into array in D3

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, d3.js

I know this question has been asked before but their solutions dont see to work for me for some reason.

I am trying to populate two arrays with data from a CSV file where:

```
name,value
alpha,34
beta,12
delta,49
gamma,89
```

What I am trying now is

```
var field1=[];
var field2=[];

d3.csv("data.csv",function(csv){
            csv.map(function(d){
                field1.push(d.name);
                field2.push(+d.value);
            })
        });

console.log("field1",field1);
console.log("field2",field2);
```

When I view console on my browser I see:

field1 Array [  ]
field2 Array [  ]

where:

```
field1:
Array[0]
  0:"alpha"
  1:"beta"
  2:"delta"
  3:"gamma"

field2:
Array[0]
  0:34
  1:12
  2:49
  3:89
```

However when I try to access field1[0], I get the value as undefined

```
field1 undefined
```

What I guess is happening is field1 array has an array of arrays of "name" column, but I'm not able to access the first element though field[0][0] either. What I get is:

```
TypeError: field1[0] is undefined
```

I'm very new to JavaScript and I don't seem to understand why the array is not populated correctly as a 1 dimensional array or if I'm doing something wrong. I am aware that I can iterate through each row while accessing csv per row but I want to store the csv values in array to be used globally in the script.

Links I have gone through are:

- https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV
- [converting a d3.csv method to d3.csv.parse method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26111455/converting-a-d3-csv-method-to-d3-csv-parse-method)
- [csv to array in d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491885/csv-to-array-in-d3-js)
- http://learnjsdata.com/read_data.html
- http://bl.ocks.org/enjalot/1525346

But I seem to be missing or overlooking something.. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that

```
d3.csv("data.csv",function(csv){
```

is an ajax call so you cannot write something like below *(your console log is called before the ajax is completed so you get unexpected results)*:

```
var field1=[];
var field2=[];

d3.csv("data.csv",function(csv){
            //executed after successful loading of data
            csv.map(function(d){

                field1.push(d.name);
                field2.push(+d.value);
            })
        });
//called before the loading of AJAX call got completed
console.log("field1",field1);
console.log("field2",field2);
```

The correct way is:

```
var field1=[];
var field2=[];

d3.csv("data.csv",function(csv){
            csv.map(function(d){
                field1.push(d.name);
                field2.push(+d.value);
            })
            //called after the AJAX is success
            console.log("field1",field1);
            console.log("field2",field2);
            console.log("field1",field1[0]);
        });
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8JjHzpr9NHKKEHW95tee?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works! However, is it not possible to somehow store this data outside the csv read in order to do something like concatenate data from multiple csv files and process it for visualization?

Comment: without nesting that is

Comment: yeah you can check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842384/importing-data-from-multiple-csv-files-in-d3 or use d3-queue to load several csv https://github.com/d3/d3-queue

Comment: Yes, this solution is correct but painfully un-scalable and results in unreadable code if you've got 20 or 30 operations on that CSV data you need to do. Stupid asynchronous methods! There has to be a better way...